# How do I analyze my bootchart in order to improve boot time?

Tags: bootchart, boot-time

I use Ubuntu 11.10.

I have boot-chart installed but I have no clue on how to use it. Someone help me and others like me out there.

How to find out what should not be running or something like that ?

So far I haven't found a normal bootchart of the same.

Also, if anyone using Ubuntu 11.10 has a boot time of less than 30 secs please post your bootchart so that I can compare.

I will attach mine here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a boot time of below 60s is nothing to worry about. You might speed it up with a SSD, a faster hard drive.

But the key in booting time is: Avoid it. Don't boot. Okay - without booting, how should you use the computer? Boot once, and then don't shut down.

If this is a problem because of noise, of energy consumption, energy price, environment: Measure the power consumption in stand by and use stand by instead of shut down.

You might as well investigate all the programs and try to find out if you really need them. Maybe you'll get one second here or there - most probably not, but maybe you invest 3600s into research which would only pay off, if you boot once per day and save one second each time over about 10 years.

But you could have a look into your logfiles (/var/log/*log) and see, if you have problems with a specific device. Such problems (frequent fsck, failing USB devices) may slow down the boot.